# Redirect new xterm's output back to the original terminal

Tags: linux, bash, xterm

For example, I have a very simple script, `ping.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/xterm -e ping localhost
```

Right now, the output of the ping only shows up in the new xterm.  I would like the output to show in both the original terminal (stdout of ping.sh) as well as in the new xterm.  Is there a way to do this?

PS: I'm struggling with a title for this.

Comment: [command line - How to send output from one terminal to another without making any new pipe or file - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261531/how-to-send-output-from-one-terminal-to-another-without-making-any-new-pipe-or-f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a weird thing to do, but this might work:

```
#!/bin/bash
f=$(mktemp)
touch "$f"
tail -f "$f" &
/usr/bin/xterm -e "sh -c 'ping localhost 2>&1 | tee -a $f'"
```

Comment: I agree its strange.  I have a C program exec-ing the ping command and reading its stdout.  Sometimes though, I want the ping command to execute in a new xterm so the user can see, and also still be readable by the C program.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, it's possible to get the file name of the terminal connected to standard input using the command `tty`, then use `tee` in the new terminal to copy the output to the old terminal.

```
/usr/bin/xterm -e "ping localhost | tee $(tty)"
```

Of course, this only works if the script is not called with redirected stdin.

In case the script is called with redirected stdin, solutions in [shell - How to get the real name of the controlling terminal? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187319/how-to-get-the-real-name-of-the-controlling-terminal) can be used. `readlink /proc/self/fd/1`, or `ps` (require some output parsing)